# 2002 Peugeot 206 Clutch won't disengage

Tags: transmission, clutch

When the car is running, I am no longer able to put it into any gear; like it would happen when you're not holding the clutch, so that is one of the reasons why I think there is something wrong with clutch.

Other, possibly relevant stuff:

- When the car is not running, the shifter seems to be working just fine and I can put it into any gear.
- If I try to start a car while in first gear, it would just jerks and die.
- When the car is running (in neutral gear), and I press and hold clutch all the way, I can hear some light scratching-like noise.
- I might be wrong on this, but clutch pedal doesn't seem to be as stiff as it was before, if that makes any sense.
- Day or two before this happened, I've noticed that the car needed stronger gas to get going. I though it was just because I got some
  bad quality fuel which is not as uncommon where I live.
- Car was recently (~two weeks ago) on a big scheduled maintenance where oil, * filters and some other stuff I can't name were changed. Shouldn't they have noticed if there was something about to break or wear off?!

Now, as my car is parked in a really tight and hard to push-out-of spot, is there anything I can do to get it going in reverse and at least get it onto the main road so I can call the road assistance service?

Edit: Forgot to mention that this happened overnight. I drove and then parked car just fine. When I came back 1 day later, problem described above occurred.

Comment: This sounds more like a problem with the master/slave for the clutch, than it does a clutch problem. You may want to check the amount of fluid in the clutch reservoir. It may use the brake reservoir doing double duty, so be aware.

Comment: Another thought, if while the engine is stopped, put the transmission into gear, press the clutch pedal, then start the car ... does the car move or does it behave normal-*ish* until you go to shift gears?

Comment: Problem ended up being a bit more serious than that. My car mechanic suggested I should change clutch basket, plate and some other stuff I forgot.

Comment: This is understandable. I was going for the easiest/cheapest things first before I went nuclear on you. Please put what you said down as an answer and select it as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem with the clutch ended up being serious. I had to replace clutch basket, plate and some other stuff I can't name. Also, some leaver was broken.

**Scratching noise** while holding a clutch that I mentioned in my question was (at least to a car mechanic guy I went to) a give-away of what's wrong with it. So, if you hear that scratching noise -- it's probably not gonna be good.

I don't think this was the smartest thing to do, but I managed to drive my car to a nearest car mechanic shop w/o clutch by starting a car and driving it in 2nd/3rd gear. Had to shut it down on each stop though.